# Entity Framework - defining get without set accessors

Tags: c#, get, ef-code-first, set, entity-framework-5

I created a new class library project in Visual Studio 2012, to define data classes in order to enable new database creation using Entity Framework code first. So I created 3 classes:

Product as next:

```
namespace MyClassLibrary
{
    public class Product
    {
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Category as next:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyClassLibrary
{
    public class Department
    {
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and ICategoryDataSource as next:

```
using System.Linq;

namespace MyClassLibrary
{
    public class ICategoryDataSource
    {
        IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }
        IQueryable<Category> Categories { get; }
    }
}
```

In the last class, I get the next error message: 'MyClassLibrary.ICategoryDataSource.Products.get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern. Automatically implemented properties must define both get and set accessors.

I do not need a setter here, please advise how can I avoid using set accessors.

Comment: Down-voter, at least say why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the name in the last code section, I assume you want `ICategoryDataSource` to be an interface, not a class:

```
using System.Linq;

namespace MyClassLibrary
{
    public interface ICategoryDataSource
    {
        IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }
        IQueryable<Category> Categories { get; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't ever have an automatic property in a concrete class which **only** has an automatic getter or automatic setter.  How would you get the data into that property in order to be able to pull it out?

You *can* however do that in abstract classes or interfaces, both of which effectively say "I don't care how data gets in here, I just require that it can be pulled out."

Probably what you need is a private setter.

```
public IQueryable<Product> Products { get; private set; }
```

is perfectly valid, in any class.

Comment: This is a very good explanation, however the big mistake I did is that I used a class instead of using an interface, as said @Jeffery Khan above, thanks a lot.